# Periodic orbit after Jordan canonical transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given 
$$B= \pmatrix{0&b\\-b&0}$$ 
Assume there exists $2\times 2$-matrices $A$ and $P$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP$. Find a periodic orbit for $\dot{y} = Ay$.

**My attempt:** I use the transformation by letting $Px = y$. Since $PB = AP$, we have: $\dot{y} = P\dot{x} = PBx = APx = Ay$. Therefore, since $x(t)=e^{(Bt)}x_0$ is a solution to $\dot{x} = Bx$, $y(t) = Pe^{(Bt)}x_0$ is a solution to $\dot{y} = Ay$. I already proved that the periodic orbit of $x(t)=e^{(Bt)}x_0$ is a circle centered at the origin with radius $(x_{01}^2+x_{02}^2)^{1/2}$, but when trying to use the same trick, by multiplying with matrix $P$ the vector $[c_1cos(bt)- c_2sin(bt), c_1sin(bt) +c_2cos(bt)]$, and adding up the squares of the two resulted components, their coefficients don't match up so that I can combine the terms $\sin^{2}{bt}$ and $\cos^{2}{bt}$. I think the result is an eclipse, but I couldn't manipulate the two components to prove it algebraically.

**My question:** Can anyone please help with the last part of my attempt above?

Comment: If you have that $x^T x = {\rm const}$ holds for $\dot{x} = Bx$, then $x^Tx = (P^{-1}y)^T(P^{-1}y)= y^T P^{-T}P^{-1} y = {\rm const}$ also holds.

Comment: @Evgeny: shouldn't we care about $(Px)^T(Px)$ though? Because we're solving for the orbit that contains $y$ as a solution, not $x$. Did I miss something here?

Comment: You use $x^T x = {\rm const}$ as a starting point; you apply transformation to this equality (namely, $x = P^{-1}y$) and get equation for $y$. I assume that you know that quadratic form $y^T Z y$ has ellipses as level sets if it meets some requirements regarding its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Evgeny: honestly, I didn't know about that property of $y^TZy$. Can you please give me a link to the proof? Luckily, the answer is indeed an ellipse, as I suspect, but yeah, I got stuck on proving it.

Comment: If $Z$ is a symmetric matrix and has only positive eigenvalues, then $y^TZy = {\rm const}$ defines ellipsoid. Matrix $MM^T$ is symmetric and always has non-negative eigenvalues; if $M$ is non-degenerate, then all eigenvalues are positive. I can't recommend any particular text: I believe that this material is covered in any book that has chapter about eigenvalues, symmetric matrices and classification of second-degree curves (~quadratic forms). I think Wikipedia might be a OK starting point.

Comment: @Evgeny: I found that property and its proof! Thanks a lot for your help.